# Magento 2: Same collection on listing page

Tags: collection, cache, product-list, magento2.2

> I have some weird problem
>
> Here is my code that write in afterGetPrice() function, I am using
>   plugin here to change price of product based on my custom table

```
$customPrice = $this->_customPriceFactory->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$product->getId())->getData();

echo $product->getId();

echo rand();

print_r($customPrice);
```

> on search page and Listing I got the same result every time Here is image

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to into phtml file then it will not work, you need to override ListProduct.php file.

Comment: You need to create getfinalprice plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try create() method.

`create()` method creates new object every time when it's call.

```
$customPrice = $this->_customPriceFactory->create();
$customPrice = $customPrice->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$product->getId())->getData();
```